# upper case and lower case in text area

Tags: javascript

I have 2 `textarea` with `maxlenghth` of `25`:

```
<textarea row='5' cols='25' maxlength="200" name="address" id="text1"
          value="text1" onkeyup="MyFunction()"></textarea>
<br><br>
<textarea row='5' cols='25' maxlength="200" name="address1" id="text2"
          value="text2" onkeyup="MyFunction()"></textarea>
```

If i am entering a lowercase character in 1st `textarea`,an uppercase character is getting printed and vice versa.But if i am entering a character in second `textarea`, the answer is not printing in the first `textarea`. Please help.

```
function MyFunction() {
    var x1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    var x2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;
    var z = '';
    for (i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
        y = x1.charAt(i);
        if (y == y.toLowerCase()) {
            z = z + y.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            z = z + y.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("text2").value = z;
    var z1 = '';
    for (j = 0; j < x2.length; j++) {
        y1 = x2.charAt(j);
        if (y1 == y1.toLowerCase()) {
            z1 = z1 + y1.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            z1 = z1 + y1.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("text1").value = z1;
}
```

Comment: can you post the full script? how are you initializing x1 and x2?

Comment: var x1=document.getElementById("text1").value;                       var x2=document.getElementById("text2").value;

Comment: please update the script so we can see the whole thing or we cant help you

Comment: ths is the text area <textarea row='5' cols='25' maxlength="200" name="address" id="text1" value="text1" onkeyup="MyFunction()"></textarea><br><br>
<textarea row='5' cols='25' maxlength="200" name="address1" id="text2" value="text2" onkeyup="MyFunction()"></textarea>

Comment: and where is this MyFunction() ? please update your question with the entire code

Comment: function MyFunction()
 {var x1=document.getElementById("text1").value;
 var x2=document.getElementById("text2").value;
  var z='';
  for(i=0;i<x1.length;i++)
  {
   y=x1.charAt(i);
  
  if(y==y.toLowerCase())
  {
  z=z+y.toUpperCase();
  }
  else
  {
  z=z+y.toLowerCase();
  }
  }
  document.getElementById("text2").value=z;
  
  var z1='';
   
   for(j=0;j<x2.length;j++)
  {
   y1=x2.charAt(j);
  
  if(y1==y1.toLowerCase())
  {
    z1=z1+y1.toUpperCase();
    
  }
  else
  {
  z1=z1+y1.toLowerCase();
  }
  }
  document.getElementById("text1").value=z1;
  }

Comment: sorry sir i am able to copy like this only

Comment: _"sorry sir i am able to copy like this only"_ - I've edited your question to add the code you posted in your comments, but in future please do this yourself using the "edit" hyperlink (just below the "javascript" tag at the bottom left of your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either do what is described above or you can check which textarea has more characters and simply update the other one

```
function MyFunction()   {
var x1=document.getElementById("text1").value; 
var x2=document.getElementById("text2").value; 
var z=''; 

if (x1.length > x2.length)
{
    for(i=0;i<x1.length;i++) 
    { 
        y=x1.charAt(i); 
        if(y==y.toLowerCase()) 
        { 
            z=z+y.toUpperCase();
        } 
        else 
        { 
            z=z+y.toLowerCase(); 
        } 
    } 
    document.getElementById("text2").value=z; 
}
else
{
    var z1=''; 
    for(j=0;j<x2.length;j++) 
    { 
        y1=x2.charAt(j); 
        if(y1==y1.toLowerCase()) 
        { 
            z1=z1+y1.toUpperCase(); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            z1=z1+y1.toLowerCase(); 
        } 
    } 

    document.getElementById("text1").value=z1; 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You call the same function regardless of which textarea the user types in, and that function updates the value of *both* textareas. Specifically, your function takes whatever was typed in the first textarea, inverts the case of the letters, and writes it to the second textarea. Then, it processes the second textarea the same way, except *using the already-updated value as a base.*

So when you type in the second textarea whatever was just typed is overwritten before it can be processed.

I'm not entirely clear what your desired behaviour is, but I would guess you intend for typing in either textarea to update the other. The first method that came to mind to achieve that was to split your function into two as follows:

```
function MyFunction1() {
    var x1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    var z = '';
    for (i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
        y = x1.charAt(i);
        if (y == y.toLowerCase()) {
            z = z + y.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            z = z + y.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("text2").value = z;
}
function MyFunction2(){
    var x2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;
    var z1 = '';
    for (j = 0; j < x2.length; j++) {
        y1 = x2.charAt(j);
        if (y1 == y1.toLowerCase()) {
            z1 = z1 + y1.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            z1 = z1 + y1.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("text1").value = z1;
}
```

And then call one the new `MyFunction1()` from the first textarea and call `MyFunction2()` from the second:

```
<textarea row='5' cols='25' maxlength="200" name="address" id="text1"
          value="text1" onkeyup="MyFunction1()"></textarea>
<br><br>
<textarea row='5' cols='25' maxlength="200" name="address1" id="text2"
          value="text2" onkeyup="MyFunction2()"></textarea>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ntqq7/